# Using object imported from interface

Tags: angular, typescript

i have question about Angular/TypeScript. Maybe it's obvious, but i need to confirm.

I'm creating interface and export it:

```
export interface MainObject {
  location: string;
  methodType: string;
  securityLevel: string;
  provider: string;
}
```

I'm importing it in component and create empty object:

```
public descriptorCreateFinal: MainObject
```

When I want to assign value to object:

```
descriptorCreateFinal.location = 'someString';
```

I see error, that 'location' is not declared.

if I create object like this:

```
public descriptorCreateFinal: MainObject = {
    location: '',
    methodType: '',
    securityLevel: '',
    provider: '',
}
```

I can assign value to 'descriptorCreateFinal.location' without any problem.

And here I would like to know, whether I really need to set values of all variables in object in declaration stage?

Answer (score 0):

### Declaration

```js
descriptorCreateFinal: MainObject
```

This only declares the object, it does not create it. So at this point it will be undefined until you create/assign it.

### Instantiation

Hence as you already noticed, when you actually assign an object it does work:

```
descriptorCreateFinal: MainObject = {
    location: '',
    methodType: '',
    securityLevel: '',
    provider: '',
}
```

### Shorthand Instantiations

However either of these should work too, depending on how strict the typescript in your project is:

```
const descriptorCreateFinal = {} as MainObject

const descriptorCreateFinal = {} as Partial<MainObject>
```

#### Alternative

*Depending on your usecase you could also use a class iso an interface, that way you can use the constructor with the 'new' keyword, but generally an interface is better if you don't need a class, because interfaces are removed when transpiling down to JS (= more lightweight).*